# SQL: Join two tables by date range and group by year

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to join two tables:

Table1:

| Task | Hours | Client | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 1 | Client A | 2023-01-01 |
| Task A | 2 | Client A | 2022-03-04 |
| Task A | 3 | Client A | 2023-01-01 |
| Task A | 4 | Client A | 2022-03-04 |
| Task B | 5 | Client A | 2023-01-01 |
| Task B | 6 | Client A | 2022-03-04 |
| Task B | 7 | Client A | 2023-01-01 |
| Task B | 8 | Client A | 2022-03-04 |

Table 2:

| Task | Time Budget | Client | Start Range | End Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 50 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
| Task A | 60 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| Task B | 80 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
| Task B | 70 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |

I want to get such a table:

| Task | Time Budget | Client | Start Range | End Range | Time spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 50 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 4 |
| Task A | 60 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 6 |
| Task B | 80 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 12 |
| Task B | 70 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 14 |

What I tried:

```
SELECT
    t2.task as task,
    t2.budget as budget,
        t1.client as client,
    t2.from_date as start_range,
    t2.to_date as end_range,
        sum(t1.hours) AS time_spent,
FROM `Table1` t1
LEFT JOIN 
    `Table2` t2 
    ON t1.task = t2.task
    AND t1.client = t2.client
    AND date(t1.time) BETWEEN t2.start_range and t2.end_range
Group by 
    task, client, start_range, end_range
```

However, this does not work. The best I can get is where it is joined, but for example the whole year 2022 is ignored.

Any help is so much appreciated!

With this query (and the suggested one) it leads to:

| Task | Time Budget | Client | Start Range | End Range | Time spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 50 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 4 |
| Task A | 60 | NULL | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | NULL |
| Task B | 80 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 12 |
| Task B | 70 | NULL | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | NULL |

Comment: What is the definition of “Time Spent” and how should it be calculated? At the moment you are just selecting t1.time, which is a date - so how are you getting to an integer value?

Comment: Sorry, that was a little too confusing. Basically, it should only be the sum of hours from table 1 that is between start_range and end_range from table 2. (edited now in the original post)

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you post the result of the query which you tried and listed above

Comment: Good idea. I added the resulting query.

Comment: Is there a reason why you put date(t1.time) but just t2.start_range and just t2.end_range? What is the data type of these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `t2.budget` is not included in the group by and you need to sum by the hour column.

If you want to include all of the table2 results, start with this table, then left join table1. Here is a post about [table joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Using https://www.db-fiddle.com/

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `Task` VARCHAR(6),
  `Hours` INTEGER,
  `Client` VARCHAR(8),
  `Time` DATE
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (`Task`, `Hours`, `Client`, `Time`)
VALUES
  ('Task A', '1', 'Client A', '2023-01-01'),
  ('Task A', '2', 'Client A', '2022-03-04'),
  ('Task A', '3', 'Client A', '2023-01-01'),
  ('Task A', '4', 'Client A', '2022-03-04'),
  ('Task B', '5', 'Client A', '2023-01-01'),
  ('Task B', '6', 'Client A', '2022-03-04'),
  ('Task B', '7', 'Client A', '2023-01-01'),
  ('Task B', '8', 'Client A', '2022-03-04');
  
  

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  `Task` VARCHAR(6),
  `Time Budget` INTEGER,
  `Client` VARCHAR(8),
  `Start Range` DATE,
  `End Range` DATE
);

INSERT INTO Table2
  (`Task`, `Time Budget`, `Client`, `Start Range`, `End Range`)
VALUES
  ('Task A', '50', 'Client A', '2023-01-01', '2023-12-31'),
  ('Task A', '60', 'Client A', '2022-01-01', '2022-12-31'),
  ('Task B', '80', 'Client A', '2023-01-01', '2023-12-31'),
  ('Task B', '70', 'Client A', '2022-01-01', '2022-12-31');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
t2.`task`,
t2.`Time Budget`,
t2.client,
t2.`Start Range`,
t2.`End Range`,
SUM(t1.hours)

FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 
ON t2.Task=t1.task
AND t2.client=t1.client
AND t1.time between t2.`Start Range` AND t2.`End Range`
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

| task | Time Budget | client | Start Range | End Range | SUM(t1.hours) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task A | 50 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 4 |
| Task A | 60 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 6 |
| Task B | 70 | Client A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 | 14 |
| Task B | 80 | Client A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | 12 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: I tried this, as this was kind of the suggestion in previous posts regarding a similar problem. However, this still leads to the issue that it only includes the 2023 figures and no 2022. If I make a broader query it shows that it leads to columns that the time_spent is matched with both 2022 and 2023 which is of course wrong.

Comment: updated with db fiddle example.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first comment brought me on the right track and with DB Fiddle I found the last  mistake on my end. Now everything works fine. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UNION` and `WHERE` to fetch data from 2 `SELECT`:

```sql
    Select * from 
    (Select a as a1
    UNION
    Select b as b1)
    WHERE b1=a1
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to elaborate a bit more on your answer. I would not be able to understand how this would hep the original poster

Comment: Sorry, I indeed dont understand this :(  What is a and b in your case? Table 1 and 2? And where should I put this in my example query?